# diagramas de flujo dfd

Tags: javascript, diagrama-de-flujo, dfd

Estoy tratando de hacer un diagrama de flujo para el siguiente código de js en dfd, tal como se ve en el código son dos for anidados.

en dfd lel pido al usuario que ingrese 6 numeros para el primer array, hasta hí funciona bien, pero si le anido el otro for pidiendo los otros 6 numeros, el ciclo nunca termina y me pide mas y mas numeros, osea se vuelve infinito

```js
let firstArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let secondArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let a = 7


for (i = 0; i <= firstArray.length; i++) {
  for (l = 0; l <= secondArray.length; l++) {
    if (firstArray[i] + secondArray[l] == a) {
      console.log(firstArray[i], secondArray[l]);
    }
  }
}
```

este es el dfd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si quieres 6 números más no deberías de anidar los `for`... En vez de 12 números vas a terminar con 36 porque harás 6 ciclos de 6 elementos ( 6x6=36).

Comment: Hola, claro pero si no los anido como los compara para saber si la suma me da k

Comment: No comprendo, el código no se cicla, las condiciones de paro e incremento estan en el mismo `for`, los bucles son finitos.